# Why do I need to boot my pc every time I turn it on

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, reboot, desktop-computer, bootrepair

Hi I installed a new motherboard in my pc and sinds then I need to boot my pc into windows every time I start it up and can’t find why it’s doing that can any one help?

Comment: Not sure I understand... If you're turning your PC on wouldn't you want it to boot into Windows or do you want it to boot into an alternative operating system like Linux? Sorry, it's just the question you are asking here is unclear.

Comment: When I start my pc it go’s in my boot menu and need to boot my pc my self in windows that is the problem it doesn’t do it bij itself

Comment: Sounds like the startup boot device in the BIOS/UEFI is set to the wrong device. Should be set to Boot Manager in order to get windoiws' boot manager to function properly. In most cases it will work if the primary harddisk is selected, but not always. If you have no boot manager choice, then select the harddisk.

Comment: Okay thanks I will look for it and try that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question completely, but here's my thoughts.

Windows has to boot up each and every time you turn the power ON.

**HOWEVER**

You can re-assign shutdown and/or the power button to either hibernate your computer to the hard drive or suspend to RAM.

Hibernate stores the contains of your RAM on the HDD or SSD and the computer uses that to return the PC to it previous condition.  This process can take a bit depending on how much RAM you have installed.  However, this is the safest option as even if the power is lost everything will be restore to the previous state.

Suspend to RAM is way faster and uses no HDD or SSD.  However, if you lose power your previous state is lost and the next time you turn on your PC it will have to boot again.